# My site doesn't load images on iPhones but does on all other browsers, mobile or desktop

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iphone, safari

I have been designing a website for my mom's business she wants to start. I finally get everything set up and deployed. Everything's working how she wanted, but when we try to go to the site on either my mom or brothers iPhone, none of the images load. The css media queries format it properly for viewing it on the iPhone is working fine, I tried it on my OnePlus 8 Pro on chrome and tor and it loaded the images properly.

The site was made in React, deployed on google firebase (not sure if this would maybe have an issue somehow but I looked it up and didnt come across anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated I have posted screen shots and code snippets below:

Here is what it should look like on desktop:
[image]

and here is what happens on iPhone:
[image]

html & css for header section:

```
    <div className="header">
  <div className="header__image">
    <div className="background__mask">
      <img className="logo_img" src={ColoredLogo} alt="logo" />

      <h1 className="header__text lineTwo">
        Focus on what you do best!
        <br /> Leave the books to us!
      </h1>
    </div>{" "}
  </div>
</div>


.header__image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 775px;
  background-image: url("./bkg_img.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.header__text {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: rgb(224, 149, 8);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
}

.myh1 {
  color: rgb(1, 51, 38);
  margin-top: 30rem;
}

.lineTwo {
  margin-top: 37rem;
}

.logo_img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}

.background__mask {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 764px) {
  .lineTwo {
    margin-top: 25rem;
  }
  .logo_img {
    margin-top: -7rem;
  }
}
```

html & css for virtual book keeping section:

```
 <div className="entrepreneurs">
  <h1 className="entrepreneurs__heading">
    Virtual Bookkeeping for Entrepreneurs
  </h1>
  <div className="body__container">
    <div className="entrepreneurs__left">
      {/* <h1>Bookkeeping for small to medium sized businesses:</h1>
    <h2>Did you know outsourcing your bookkeeping can: </h2> */}
      <img src={logo} alt="" />
    </div>
    <div className="entrepreneurs__right">
      <ul>
        <li>✓ Save Your Business Money</li>
        <li>✓ Increase Your Cash Flow</li>
        <li>✓ Reduce Overhead Costs</li>
        <li>✓ Save Money on Your Taxes</li>
        <li>✓ Better Analysis of Your Business</li>
        <li>✓ Help You Get Investors</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.entrepreneurs__right > ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.entrepreneurs__left > img {
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 2.5%;
}
.entrepreneurs {
  text-align: center;
}
.entrepreneurs > h1 {
  font-size: 55px;
}

.body__container {
  color: teal;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.entrepreneurs__right {
  color: rgb(70, 70, 70);
}

.entrepreneurs__right > ul > li {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.entrepreneurs__right > ul > li {
  line-height: 4rem;
}

.entrepreneurs__heading {
  font-size: 60px;
  color: rgb(1, 51, 38);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0.25px 0.25px #000000;
}

@media (max-width: 1156px) {
  .body__container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .entrepreneurs__right {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Are you able to run an iOS device simulator and reproduce it locally on your machine? If you can you can connect a debugger to the simulator via Safari and view the rendered result and inspect the DOM to see why it is different.

Comment: I am on windows, so I guess I would have to look into an ios simulator for it, and debug that way, I wasnt sure how much debugging, so I figured I would ask before I dive wayy to deep and solving an issue no one has yet, or any idea the cause, it seems really weird to me, especially consdier most search  results on google where from like 2011 when safari would just not load images cause there was not enough ram to handle it. But by all means that seems ridiculous by todays phone standards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `webp` format for your images. Safari supports this format only since the newest update (version 14).
If your Safari version is older than version 14 your images will not work without implementing a fallback to a supported image format.

https://caniuse.com/?search=webp

Comment: Hello this was part of the problem! I uploaded the images to be hosted on imgur and then also removed background-attatchment: fixed; now I just got to get the images to resize properly. But thank you!